# How to print two ArrayLists to a csv file with multiple columns?

Tags: java, csv, arraylist

I have two array lists like shown below,

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.*;

class Reader {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {

        ArrayList<String> animal = new ArrayList<>();
        animal.add("Dog");
        animal.add("Cat");
        animal.add("Mouse");

        ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
            numbers.add(i);
        }

        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("animals.csv");

        for (String ani : animal) {
            writer.println(ani + ",");
        }

        writer.close();    
    }
}
```

I want the output to be like this in the .csv file.

```
Dog,1,2,3,4,5,
Cat,6,7,8,9,10,
Mouse,11,12,13,14,15,
```

When I use for-loops, the output of the array lists gets printed one below the other in the .csv file.

How do I format the array lists the way I desired, so it looks like this in Excel?
[image]

Comment: `writer.println(ani + ",");` remove ln and use `writer.print(ani + ",");`

Comment: But how do we print the numbers arraylist next to it?

Comment: @KematRochi: what is the condition for number? Is it fixed 5 numbers for each animal?

Comment: why not use hashmap?

Comment: @TanmayBaid - Yes, the five numbers are fixed!

Comment: try something like this `ani/5=1?someString.append("Dog"):ani/5=2?someString.append("cat"):somestring.append("RAT")` or use `if-else`

Comment: here somestring is stringBuffer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `writer.print()` instead of `writer.println()`

Notice 'ln' in the method name you are using, which means print line.

---

Update: To also add numbers along with animal:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    ArrayList<String> animal = new ArrayList<>();
    animal.add("Dog");
    animal.add("Cat");
    animal.add("Mouse");

    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
        numbers.add(i);
    }

    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("animals.csv");

    List<String> row = new ArrayList<>();
    int i = 0;
    for (String ani : animal) {
        row.add(ani);
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            row.add(String.valueOf(numbers.get(i++)));
        }
        writer.println(String.join(",", row));
        row.clear();
    }

    writer.close();
}
```

Comment: stringjoiner is available in `java8` too

Comment: I tried this code and seems to be working great to meet my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Your writer method is printing a line. You need to use just print.

So `writer.println(ani + ",");` becomes `writer.print(ani + ",");`

Also, to add numbers as you asked you can do this as an alternative. This works as you said you have only 5 elements in each row after animal name.

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("animals.csv");
int rowCounter = 0;
for (String ani : animals) {
  writer.print(ani);
  for (int i = rowCounter * 5; i < (rowCounter * 5 + 5); i++) {
    writer.print("," + numbers.get(i));
  }
  writer.println();
  rowCounter++;
}

writer.close();
```