# Add new column along with previous columns in csv in java (duplicate)

Tags: java, csv

I have an arraylist which would be different in size with different times . I want to store it as separate column in a csv along with previous columns. I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34590971/java-append-new-column-to-csv-file) but It's  actually not working. But in the second solution It adds all value in a row what actually I don't want.
Possible duplication would be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40540797/how-to-print-two-arraylists-to-a-csv-file-with-multiple-columns).

```
public class writeLine {
    public static void generateCSV(PrintWriter pw, ArrayList<Double> list,int n) throws IOException{
        for(int i= 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            pw.print(String.format("%f%n", list.get(i)));
        }
        pw.flush();
    }
}
```

Here is my code which add values in the same column. But I want each time as a new column along with previous column. What should I modify in this code?

I also tried first to read my csv then I add new arraylist values. But the problem is when my arraylist size in greater than the csv rows it will not add the rest of values of the arraylist.